# How to use task id in custom field in Jira?

Tags: jira

I have a local Jira instance running and I want to customize the issue screen. My wish is to display an additional field which would be an url built using the issue id and project id. For example, for given task MyProject-103 in project MyProject, I wand to show the link `http://myserver:1234/anotherserver/MyProject?id=MyProject-103`.

I have seen how to add a custom field in the documentation ([here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Adding+a+Custom+Field)), but couldn't find how to use the task id to build it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two ways to achieve this:

1. Use the [Script Runner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner) plugin to attach a post function to the `create` transition, that will generate the URL and will save it in your custom field.
2. Use Jira's [AJS](http://orangoo.com/labs/AJS/) (Similar to jQuery) to create this URL on the client side.

here is code fro the first solution:

```
from com.atlassian.jira import ComponentManager
cfm = ComponentManager.getInstance().getCustomFieldManager()

project = issue.getProject().get("name")
id = issue.getId()
url = "http://myserver:1234/anotherserver/" + project + "?id=" + project + "-" + id

issue.setCustomFieldValue(cfm.getCustomFieldObjectsByName("My Custom Field"),url)
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed. Just one note, I'm using JIRA 5.2 and setCustomFieldValue did not seem to work as I expected... So I just built my url and returned it

Answer (score 0):

If you are in JIRA 5.1 and earlier the Velocity View field from the JIRA Toolkit plugin will do it for you. Since then I'd recommend the Script Runner plugin as well. This functionality is frustratingly close to the Bugzilla ID field but that is read-only